# Unable to import _timestamp from mapping using ElasticDump

Tags: database, elasticsearch, import

I have some JSON files that come from an ElasticSearch database and I'm trying to import them with ElasticDump.

This is the mapping file: "mylog.mapping.json"

```
[
"{\"mylog\":{\"mappings\":{\"search_log\":{\"_timestamp\":{\"enabled\":true,\"store\":true},\"properties\":{\"preArray\":{\"type\":\"long\"},\"preId\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"filteredSearch\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"hits\":{\"type\":\"long\"},\"search\":{\"type\":\"string\"},\"searchType\":{\"properties\":{\"name\":{\"type\":\"string\"}}}}}}}}"
]
```

And the file that contains the data itself: "mylog.json"

```
{"_index":"mylog","_type":"search_log","_id":"AU5AcRy7dbXLQfUndnNS","_score":1,"_source":{"searchType":{"name":"TypeSearchOne"},"search":"test","filteredSearch":"test","hits":1470,"preId":"","preArray":[47752,51493,52206,50159,52182,53243,43237,51329,42772,44938,44945,44952,42773,58319,43238,48963,52856,52185,47751,61542,51327,42028,51341,45356,44853,44939,48587,42774,43063,98779,46235,53533,47745,48844,44979,53209,47738,98781,47757,44948,44950,48832,97529,52186,96033,53002,48419,44943,44955,52179]},"fields":{"_timestamp":1435600231611}}
{"_index":"mylog","_type":"search_log","_id":"AU5AcSdcdbXLQfUndnNd","_score":1,"_source":{"searchType":{"name":"TypeSearchTwo"},"search":"squared","filteredSearch":"squared","hits":34,"preId":null,"preArray":null},"fields":{"_timestamp":1435600234333}}
{"_index":"mylog","_type":"search_log","_id":"AU5AcSiZdbXLQfUndnNj","_score":1,"_source":{"searchType":{"name":"TypeSearchOne"},"search":"test","filteredSearch":"test","hits":1354,"preId":"","preArray":[55808,53545,53543,53651,55937,53544,54943,54942,54941]},"fields":{"_timestamp":1435600234649}}

...

{"_index":"mylog","_type":"search_log","_id":"AU5DSVzLdbXLQfUndnPp","_score":1,"_source":{"searchType":{"name":"TypeSearchOne"},"search":"lee","filteredSearch":"lee","hits":39,"preId":"53133","preArray":null},"fields":{"_timestamp":1435647958219}}
{"_index":"mylog","_type":"search_log","_id":"AU5D7M42dbXLQfUndnR9","_score":1,"_source":{"searchType":{"name":"TypeSearchOne"},"search":"leerwww","filteredSearch":"leerwww","hits":39,"preId":"53133","preArray":null},"fields":{"_timestamp":1435658669622}}
```

In my attempts to import this data in my ElasticSearch server, I've tried the following ElasticDump commands:

```
elasticdump --input=/home/user/Desktop/LOGDATA/mylog.mapping.json --output=http://localhost:9200/mylog --type=mapping
elasticdump --input=/home/user/Desktop/LOGDATA/mylog.json --output=http://localhost:9200/mylog --type=data
```

After this, the data is available, however, the `_timestamp` field is nowhere to be seen. If I check the mappings, this is what I obtain:

```
user@computer:~$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/mylog/_mapping'

{
    "mylog":{
        "mappings":{
            "search_log":{
                "properties":{
                    "preArray":{"type":"long"},
                    "preId":{"type":"string"},
                    "filteredSearch":{"type":"string"},
                    "hits":{"type":"long"},
                    "search":{"type":"string"},
                    "searchType":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"string"}}}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `_timestamp` field isn't there, even though it was specified in the mapping. Why is happening this and what can I do to import the data without losing the timestamp?

Comment: What version is this?

Comment: @pickypg 2.3.3 for ElasticSearch and 2.3.0 for ElasticDump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2.0, [`_timestamp` is deprecated and a special type of field known as a meta-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/mapping-timestamp-field.html). It still exists in 5.0 (at least for now), but you should not depend upon it and you should expect it to be removed.

As with other meta-fields, you are not supposed to be able to modify its mappings (e.g., specifying `stored: true`) nor are you intended to be able to set it as part of the document.

What you are supposed to do is to set the field as a request parameter:

```
PUT my_index/my_type/1?timestamp=1435600231611
{"searchType":{"name":"TypeSearchOne"},"search":"test","filteredSearch":"test","hits":1470,"preId":"","preArray":[47752,51493,52206,50159,52182,53243,43237,51329,42772,44938,44945,44952,42773,58319,43238,48963,52856,52185,47751,61542,51327,42028,51341,45356,44853,44939,48587,42774,43063,98779,46235,53533,47745,48844,44979,53209,47738,98781,47757,44948,44950,48832,97529,52186,96033,53002,48419,44943,44955,52179]}
```

I do not know enough about ElasticDump to know if it's possible to instruct it to do "the right thing", but there's actually a superior option here:

Modify your JSON input to remove `_timestamp` and replace it with an ordinary field named `timestamp` (or whatever name you choose).

```
"mappings": {
  "my_type": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Do note that your ElasticDump input separates `_timestamp` within `fields`, not from the `source`, so you'd have to ensure that you do a find/replace that properly joins them together:

```
},"fields":{"_timestamp"
```

should be:

```
,"timestamp"
```